# Не одинаковые элементы в двух массивах

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Моя задача - найти не общие элементы из двух известных массивов, используя только указатели (без индексов). Я написал программу, которая находит общие элементы, и я думаю, что она очень близка, скажите мне, что нужно изменить

~
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main()
{
    int arr[8] = { 1, 2 ,4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15};
    int brr[5] = { 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 };
    int crr[5] = {0};
    int* a, * b, * c, * aend, * bend;

    a = arr;
    aend = a + 8 - 1;
    b = brr;
    bend = b + 5 - 1;
    c = crr;

    for (int *a = arr; a <= aend; a++)
    {
        for (int *b = brr; b <= bend; b++)
        {
            if (*a == *b)
            {
                *c = *b;
                c++;
            }          
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d ", crr[i]);
}
```

~

Вывод сейчас: 2, 9, 10
Вывод который нужен:1, 4, 8, 11, 15, 5, 6

Comment: А что с этой программой не так?

Comment: `for (int *a` - по-моему нет смысла объявлять переменную в цикле, если она уже объявлена выше по коду

Comment: @andreymal сейчас она находит общие элементы, а нужно чтобы не общие

Comment: Добавить ещё один цикл по массивам a и b с проверкой отсутствия чисел в массиве c, наверное

Comment: @andreymal моя ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для простоты понимания программы и сокращения объёма кода, рекомендую проверку наличия элемента в массиве вынести в отдельную функцию. Вот так:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

#define A_LEN 8
#define B_LEN 5 
#define C_LEN A_LEN+B_LEN

int present(int value, int *array, int  len) {

    // Проверяет, присутствует ли значение value в массиве array длинной len

    int j, result=0;

    for (j=0; j<len; j++) {
       if ( *(array+j) == value) {
          result = 1;
          break;
       } 
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[A_LEN] = { 1, 2 ,4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15};
    int brr[B_LEN] = { 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 };
    int crr[C_LEN];
    int *a, *b, *c, *aend, *bend, len;

    aend = arr + A_LEN - 1;
    bend = brr + B_LEN - 1;
    c = crr;

    // Проверяем наличие элементов A в B
    for (a = arr; a <= aend; a++)
    {
       if (present(*a, brr, B_LEN) == 0) {
           *c = *a;
           c++;
       }
    }

    // Проверяем наличие элементов B в A
    for (b = brr; b <= bend; b++)
    {
       if (present(*b, arr, A_LEN) == 0) {
           *c = *b;
           c++;
       }
    }

    len = c - crr;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ", crr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```